# onClick event not firing on simple code (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs

A bit confused as to why the event listener isn't firing. I also tried not commenting out the bind since I don't think it is necessary, but it still does not work. Not sure what the error is here...

I also triple checked the last line (rendering App component at id=root on my main html tag... that is fine).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {text: 'X'};
    this.i = 0;
    this.val = ['X', 'O'];
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }

  //click to change state from X to O.
  update() {
    console.log("clicked");
    // if(this.i === 0) {
    //   this.setState({text: this.val[1]});
    //   this.i = this.i + 1;
    // } else {
    //   this.setState({text: this.val[0]});
    //   this.i = this.i - 1;
    // }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        <Box text={this.state.text} onClick={this.update}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Box extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className = "box" >{this.props.text}</button>
      // <button className = "box">hi</button>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use the passed onClick prop on Box.

```js
class Box extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="box" onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.text}</button>
      // <button className="box">hi</button>
    );
  }
}
```

That should work!

Comment: You are a legend!!! tysm. It's so weird because in a similar exercise, I didn't pass the onClick event as a prop, but this time I needed to.